# How to decompress a file compressed by LZRW1?

Tags: archive, lzw

I have a few files and I believe that they are compressed by LZRW1 algoritm (they have few same bytes on start of file (`21 48 5A 4C`) and I found somewhere that it's a LZRW1 file signature).
How I can decompress it? Maybe someone knows some software for it?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English!

Comment: You want to decompress it from a desktop application, or are you asking for help on doing this in code?

Comment: @LordWilmore It's will be better to decompress it via desktop app (Linux or Windows).